# Why won't jQuery animate() work with variable css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a jQuery/javascript beginner and for fun I'm trying to make a snake game. I think I'm pretty close to getting movement except when I change directions via keyboard arrows, it's not working how I'd expect. For example, the snake will automatically start moving right. If I hit down it will go down BUT still continue to go right. If I hit left, it'll go left but continue to go down.

This might be just a fundamental error in my code or something more obvious.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgjg6914/

```
var direction = 'left';
var plusOrMinus = '+=25px';

// create the object literal
var aniArgs = {}; 

function myFunction(){
    aniArgs[direction] = plusOrMinus;
    var posTop = $('.snake_bit').position().top + 25;
    var posLeft = $('.snake_bit').position().left + 25;
    if (posTop > 500 || posLeft > 500 || posTop < 25 || posLeft < 25) {
        gameOver();
        return;
    }
    $('.snake_bit').animate(aniArgs, 0);
    console.log('top: ' + posTop + ' left: ' + posLeft);
}
function gameOver(){
    clearInterval(theInterval);
    console.log('game over');
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      direction = 'top';
      plusOrMinus = '-=25px';
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      direction = 'top';
      plusOrMinus = '+=25px';
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      direction = 'left';
      plusOrMinus = '-=25px';
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      plusOrMinus = '+=25px';
      direction = 'left';
    }
});

var theInterval = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when you set a new direction, you leave the previous one in `aniArgs`.

Quick fix: in your `keydown` handler, in all of the `if`s, you need to reset `aniArgs`.

```
if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    aniArgs = {};  // clear previous movement
    direction = 'top';
    plusOrMinus = '-=25px';
}
```

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/zgjg6914/5/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if it's good idea to use time interval to check any behaviour inside game. Read sth about preparing games [with html5 canvas element](http://canvasengine.net/) (jquery will be also useful there) - imho it's more proper way to create games inside browser